# Calculadora C# e interação com teclado

Tags: c#, winforms

Galera é o seguinte: eu estou fazendo uma calc em C# e queria por nela calculo de raiz. Eu conseguir, o problema é que o calculo só é feito com o valor que eu por na variavel primeiro. Não consigo por nessa parte do codigo pra ele calcular um valor que eu digitar no teclado ou que eu clicar na tela. Alguem pode ajudar?

```
 private void buttonRaiz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double primeiro = 2;          

        double resutado = Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sqrt(primeiro));

        Tela.Text = resutado.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: Não está claro.

Answer (score 1):

SidSan,

Se você está usando o Windows Forms você precisa colocar uma TextBox na tela também.
   Depois você associa o valor de textBox para dentro da sua variável "primeiro". Exemplo:

```
double primeiro;
primeiro =  Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
```

Para seu TextBox aceitar só números, pois se o usuário digitar uma letra vai aparecer um erro em tempo de execução, dentro do evento KeyPress deve ter o seguinte código:

```
Private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (!(e.KeyChar >= '0' && e.KeyChar <= '9') && e.KeyChar != 8) e.Handled = true;
}
```

Agora vou colocar alguns links para você ler:

[C# TextBox Control](http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/cs-textbox.htm)

[TextBox Class - System.Windows.Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?view=netframework-4.8)

[C# - Redimensionando um TextBox](http://www.macoratti.net/18/12/c_txtredim1.htm)

[]'s,

Fabio I.